# При отправке UDP multicast не получаю ответов

Tags: golang, windows-10, udp, firewall

Реализую WS-Discovery на Golang. Отправляю Probe мультикастом. Временами перестает работать. Методом проб и ошибок, опытным путем выяснил, что при процедуре включения/отключения брандмауэра Windows, все начинает работать. Но через какое-то время код снова перестает работать.

Листинг функции отправки UDP:

```golang
func sendUDPMulticast (msg* string, locAddr string) []string {
    cnl := make(chan string)
    var resEnv []string
    UDPAddr,err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp","239.255.255.250:3702")
    if err  != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: " , err)
    }

    Conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, UDPAddr)
    if err  != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: " , err)
    }

    defer Conn.Close()

    _, port, _ := net.SplitHostPort(Conn.LocalAddr().String())
    address := "["+ locAddr + "]:" + port

    go listenUDP(address, cnl)

    buf := []byte(*msg)
    _, err = Conn.Write(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(*msg, err)
    }

    for{
        select {
        case res, ok := <-cnl:
            _ = res
            if ok {
                resEnv = append(resEnv, res)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Channel closed!")
            }
        case <- time.After(time.Second*5):
            fmt.Println("resEnv", resEnv)
            return resEnv
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Функция чтения:

```golang
func listenUDP( address string, cnl chan string ) {
    UDPAddr,err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", address)
    if err  != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: " , err)
    }
    ln, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", UDPAddr)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer ln.Close()

    for {
        buffer := make([]byte, 4096)

        n, _, err := ln.ReadFrom(buffer)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        }
        cnl <- string(buffer[0:n])
    }
}
```

Выяснил, что программа зависает на следующей строке:

```golang
n, _, err := ln.ReadFrom(buffer)
```

Может кто подсказать, почему программа зависает и для ее ввода в работоспособный режим необходимо включить и выключить брандмауэр?

Comment: Смотрите логи файрвола. Смотрите Wireshark, фильтруйте по UDP. Если иногда работает что то происходит вне вашей программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Пришлось спуститься c транспортного уровня на сетевой уровень (IP). Для этого использовал пакет https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4. Предположительно, проблема была в том, что в Go UDP реализован в соответствии со стандартом POSIX.